# Access to android unlock screen

Tags: android, android-intent

I m  new to android. I want to develop an app that will initiate from the unlock screen.
For e.g if the current (original) password/pattern to unlock the screen is '1234', after which user will be directed to  home, But if my app is installed, there will be 2 passwords/patterns to unlock the screen. So,

1-if the user enters the original password, it will be directed to home.
2- if the user enters the alternative second password, after some work, he will be directed to home as well.

I m new to android and don't know its access level and stuff like that. So plz help me by giving me some references to work on and suggest if this is doable or not.

Comment: This is not possible using the Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The unlock screen is built into the operating system framework and is not something you can change through a simply APK replacement. To do what you're describing correctly, you would have to modify the OS for your specific device.